# External script adds to window, but added functions are undefined in Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, hubspot

So, unfortunately I need to embed a Hubspot form in my Angular app. This is done by including an external script and running some Javascript code to create a form on the page.

The following script needs to be included:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
```

And then you can run hbspt.forms.create() to create the form. Not very interesting, right.

But what is interesting, is that this code doesn't work when using it in an Angular app. I've prepared a Stackblitz for an Angular project, and a project without a framework. Both have the above code in the index.html:

**Angular:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdsz3h
**No framework:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ld9ypn

Now, if you open up your console on the pages and enter hbspt.forms.create(), in Angular it will result in `undefined`. The framework-less project however, works as expected and shows that it is a function. What's happening here and how can I get it to work in Angular?

Comment: can you add link to stackblitz with code to edit?

Comment: @Mac_W I've updated the links

Comment: The Angular app doesn't run. Getting error "Error: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined"

Comment: @Mickers That appears to be part of the problem. It runs on Firefox, but Chrome throws that error. Neither browser shows the intended behaviour, however.

Answer (score 2):

See line 32 of [HubSpot Forms V2 Debug.js](https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-debug.js)
For some reason (didn't look too far into) they loop through and set all listed properties (lines 21/23) to undefined. One of these being `window.Promise`.

Then when `zone.evergreen.js` picks up on the activity, specifically [this bit of code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/58b29f1503a180fdfb8feb73a30d0c4448afad9a/packages/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts#L456), it throws a `Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`, as `NewNativePromise` would be `window.Promise`, which is now set to `undefined`.

I've only seen this when loading the script dynamically. When placing the script as you've shown in the `index.html`, everything seems to run fine. Might be winning a race-condition however...

Tried a few things like running it in it's own Zone.fork and ngZone.runOutsideAngular, but never figured it out.